# Integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(2-x)}{2-x^{2}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

a) Calculate the following integral:

$ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(2-x)}{2-x^{2}}dx $;

b) Prove that $ f(1+0)=\ln 3 $, where $ f(x)=\displaystyle\int_{x}^{x^{3}}\frac{1}{\ln t}dt $.

I tried solving them by substitution or partial integration, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your part (b), because $f(1+0) = f(1) = 0,$, not $\ln(3)$.

Comment: After looking at your first integral in Maple, I doubt it has a simple expression. It seems to include the function dilog

Comment: @DavidBowman $f(x+0)$ is a frequently used notation for the right-hand limit of $f$ at $x$. It is also a notation that frequently confuses people not familiar with it.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. If the questions are _very closely_ related, it can make sense to have several parts in one question, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I see. I'm used to the good old $f(x+)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

Let $I$ denote the value of the definite integral,

$$I:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(2-x\right)}}{2-x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\approx0.215993.$$

One could of course calculate $I$ by brute force in terms of dilogarithms and then employ polylog identities to reduce the number of independent dilogarithm terms appearing in the result as much as possible. But this strategy is like cracking peanuts with a sledgehammer. The final result is in fact elementary, and clever use of symmetry can avoid any mention of dilogs altogether:

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(2-x\right)}}{2-x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+t\right)}}{2-\left(1-t\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left[x=1-t\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+t\right)}}{1+2t-t^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{1}^{0}\frac{\left(1+u\right)^{2}\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}}{2\left(1+2u-u^{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{\left(-2\right)}{\left(1+u\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u;~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}}{1+2u-u^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(2\right)}}{1+2u-u^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1+u\right)}}{1+2u-u^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\ln{\left(2\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+2u-u^{2}}-I,\\
\end{align}$$

and thus,

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+2u-u^{2}}\\
&=\ln{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{2-v^{2}};~~~\small{\left[u=1-v\right]}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{1-w^{2}};~~~\small{\left[v=\sqrt{2}\,w\right]}\\
&=\frac{\ln{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(2-x)}{2-x^{2}}dx = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \left( \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(2-x)}{(\sqrt{2}-x)}dx + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(2-x)}{(\sqrt{2}+x)} dx \right)$$

The first integral could be rewritten as

$$I_1 = \int^{\sqrt{2}}_{\sqrt{2}-1}\frac{\ln(2-\sqrt{2})+\log(1+t/(2-\sqrt{2}))}{t}dt$$

Now using

$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x) = - \int^x_0 \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} \,dt$$

We get

$$I_1 = \log(2-\sqrt{2})\log(\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}+1)+\mathrm{Li}_2(-1/\sqrt{2}) - \mathrm{Li}_2(-1 - \sqrt{2})$$

Similarly

$$I_2 = -\log(2) \log(\sqrt{2}-1
) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1 - 1/\sqrt{2}) - \mathrm{Li}(2 - \sqrt{2})$$

Finally we have

$$I_1+I_2 = -\log(2) \log(\sqrt{2}-1 ) + \mathrm{Li}_2(1 - 1/\sqrt{2}) -\mathrm{Li}_2(2 - \sqrt{2})+\\\log(2-\sqrt{2})\log(\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}+1))+\mathrm{Li}_2(-1/\sqrt{2}) -\mathrm{Li}_2(-1 - \sqrt{2}))$$

AND

$$I = \frac{I_1+I_2}{2\sqrt{2}}$$